# How to extract the source of images inside class div in html string

Tags: javascript, html

I have regular expression for extracting the source of images in html string, that works fine.
The output is in urls array:

```
var m,
urls = [],
str = '<img class="d-block mx-auto" src="http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/66189-759x493.jpg" />,
rex = /<img[^>]+src="?([^"\s]+)"?\s*\alt="First slide">/g;
      while ( m = rex.exec( str ) ) {
          urls.push( m[1] );
      }
console.log(urls);  // ["http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/66189-759x493.jpg",...]
```

However I want rex that gets only the source of images inside class carousel-item :

```
str = '<div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/66189-759x493.jpg" />';
```

Comment: reg exp on html is not a good idea, make it a fragment and query on it.

Comment: arre you able to use DOMParser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would skip the regular expression and use DOM methods to get to the content you want.

Using template or DomParser and querySelector

```js
var str = '<div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/66189-759x493.jpg" /></div>';


var temp = document.createElement("template");
temp.innerHTML = str
console.log(Array.from(temp.content.querySelectorAll(".carousel-item img")).map(x => x.src))

var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html")
console.log(Array.from(doc.querySelectorAll(".carousel-item img")).map(x => x.src))
```

Comment: hello, i am using react native can i use DomParser ?